# Combination Sum python recursion scope

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, scope

I implemented a combination sum algorithm to the following problem:

```
# Given an array: [10,1,2,7,6,1,5]
# and a target: 8
# Find the solution set that adds up to the target
# in this case:
# [1, 7]
# [1, 2, 5]
# [2, 6]
# [1, 1, 6]

def cominbationSum(arr, target):
    arr =sorted(arr)
    res = []
    path = []
    dfs_com(arr, 0, target, path, res)
    return res

def dfs_com(arr, curr, target, path, res):
    if target == 0:
        res.append(path)
        return
    if target < 0:
        return
    for i in range(curr, len(arr)):
        if i > curr and arr[i] == arr[i-1]: # skip duplicates
            continue
        path.append(arr[i])
        dfs_com(arr, i+1, target - arr[i], path, res)
        path.pop(len(path)-1)


print cominbationSum([10,1,2,7,6,1,5], 8)
```

My algorithm generates the proper combinations, but it has a problem returning `res`. It returns `res` as `[[],[],[],[]]` rather than `[[1, 1, 6],[1, 2, 5],[1, 7],[2, 6]]`. Any idea why path isn't appending to res properly?

Comment: What's the python version?

Comment: @Kasramvd python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a reference issue. Try:

```
if target == 0:
    res.append(path[:])
    return
```

This will create a shallow copy of `path`, so any `pop` performed on `path` later in the code will have no effect on the lists inside `res`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
res.append(path)
```

to

```
res.append(path[:])
```

so you are getting a copy of path instead of the path itself.  The problem is because you are removing elements in this line:

```
path.pop(len(path)-1)
```